# Correct way of vectorizing "lookup" function

Tags: r, rstudio

I am looking for a fast and efficient way to compute the problem described below. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

I have a couple of very large csv files that have different information about the same object, but in my final calculation I need all of the attributes in the different table. I am trying to calculate the load of a large number of electrical substations, first I have a list of unique electrical substations;

```
Unique_Substations <- data.frame(Name = c("SubA", "SubB", "SubC", "SubD"))
```

In another list I have information about the customers behind these substations;

```
Customer_Information <- data.frame(
  Customer = 1001:1010, 
  SubSt_Nm = sample(unique(Unique_Substations$Name), 10, replace = TRUE), 
  HouseHoldType = sample(1:2, 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

And in another list I have information about the, let's say, solar panels on these customers roofs (for different years);

```
Solar_Panels <- data.frame(
  Customer = sample(1001:1010, 10, replace = TRUE), 
  SolarPanelYear1 = sample(10:20, 10, replace = TRUE), 
  SolarPanelYear2 = sample(15:20, 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Now I want see what the load is for each substation for each year. I have a household load and a solar panel load normalised for each type of household or the solarpanel;

```
SolarLoad <- data.frame(Load = c(0, -10, -10, 5))
HouseHoldLoad <- data.frame(Type1 = c(1, 3, 5, 2), Type2 = c(3, 5, 6, 1))
```

So now I have to match up these lists;

```
ML_SubSt_Cust <- sapply(Unique_Substations$Name, 
                        function(x) which(Customer_Information$SubSt_Nm %in% x == TRUE))

ML_Cust_SolarP <- sapply(Customer_Information$Customer, 
                         function(x) which(Solar_Panels$Customer %in% x == TRUE))
```

(Here I use the `which(xxx %in% x == TRUE)` method because I need multiple matches and `match()` only returns one match

And now we come to my big question (but probably not my only problem with this method) at last. I want to calculate the maximum load on each substation for each year. To this end I had first written a for loop that looped through the Unique_Substations list, which is of course highly inefficient. After that I tried to speed it up using `outer()` but I don't think I have properly vectorized my function. My maximum function looks as follows (I only wrote it out for the solar panel part to keep it simple);

```
GetMax <- function(i, Yr) {
  max(sum(Solar_Panels[unlist(ML_Cust_SolarP[ML_SubSt_Cust[[i]]], use.names= FALSE),Yr])*SolarLoad)
}
```

I'm sure this is not efficient at all but I have no clue how to do it in any other way.

To get my final results I use a outer function;

```
Results <- outer(1:nrow(Unique_Substations), 1:2, Vectorize(GetMax))
```

In my example all of these data frames are much much larger (40000 rows each or so), so I really need some good optimization of the functions involved. I tried to think of ways to vectorize the function but I couldn't work it out. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Now that I fully understand the accepted awnser I have another problem. My actual `Customer_Information` is 188k rows long and my actual `HouseHoldLoad` is 53k rows long. Needless to say this does not `merge()` very well. Is there another solution to this problem that does not require `merge()` or for loops that are too slow?

Comment: For one thing, you don't need `data.frames` since there's only one data type in each object. Vectors and matrices will suffice.  Next, rather than `which(foo %in% bar ==TRUE)` , just `which(bar == foo)` (where `foo` is a scalar and `bar` is your vector or matrix) .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft `which(foo %in% bar == TRUE)` is the same as `which(foo %in% bar)` and not as `which(bar == foo)`. Take `bar=c(0,1)` and `foo= c(1,0)` and the difference is apparent. I agree you can use either when `foo` contains only a single element, but they're not the same.

Comment: @JorisMeys  Thanks -- good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: `set.seed()` when generating random data! I did `set.seed(1000)` before your code for these results.

I think a bit of `merge`-ing and `dplyr` can help here. First, we get the data into a better shape:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

HouseHoldLoad <- melt(HouseHoldLoad, value.name="Load") %>% 
  select(HouseHoldType=variable, Load) %>% 
  mutate(HouseHoldType=gsub("Type", "", HouseHoldType))

Solar_Panels <- melt(Solar_Panels, id.vars="Customer", 
                     value.name="SPYearVal") %>%
  select(Customer, SolarPanelYear=variable, SPYearVal) %>%
  mutate(SolarPanelYear=gsub("SolarPanelYear", "", SolarPanelYear))

dat <- merge(Customer_Information, Solar_Panels, by="Customer")
```

That gives us:

```
##    Customer SubSt_Nm HouseHoldType SolarPanelYear SPYearVal
## 1      1001     SubB             1              1        16
## 2      1001     SubB             1              2        18
## 3      1001     SubB             1              2        16
## 4      1001     SubB             1              1        20
## 5      1002     SubD             2              1        16
## 6      1002     SubD             2              1        13
## 7      1002     SubD             2              2        20
## 8      1002     SubD             2              2        18
## 9      1003     SubA             1              2        15
## 10     1003     SubA             1              1        16
## 11     1005     SubC             2              2        19
## 12     1005     SubC             2              1        10
## 13     1006     SubA             1              1        15
## 14     1006     SubA             1              2        19
## 15     1007     SubC             1              1        17
## 16     1007     SubC             1              2        19
## 17     1009     SubA             1              1        10
## 18     1009     SubA             1              1        18
## 19     1009     SubA             1              2        18
## 20     1009     SubA             1              2        18
```

Now we just group and summarize:

```
dat %>% group_by(SubSt_Nm, SolarPanelYear) %>% 
  summarise(mx=max(sum(SPYearVal)*SolarLoad))

##   SubSt_Nm SolarPanelYear  mx
## 1     SubA              1 295
## 2     SubA              2 350
## 3     SubB              1 180
## 4     SubB              2 170
## 5     SubC              1 135
## 6     SubC              2 190
## 7     SubD              1 145
## 8     SubD              2 190
```

If you use `data.table` vs data frames, it should be pretty speedy even with 40K entries.

**UPDATE** For those who cannot install `dplyr`, this just uses `reshape2` (hopefully that is installable)

```
library(reshape2)

HouseHoldLoad <- melt(HouseHoldLoad, value.name="Load")
colnames(HouseHoldLoad) <- c("HouseHoldType", "Load")
HouseHoldLoad$HouseHoldType <- gsub("Type", "", HouseHoldLoad$HouseHoldType)

Solar_Panels <- melt(Solar_Panels, id.vars="Customer", value.name="SPYearVal")
colnames(Solar_Panels) <- c("Customer", "SolarPanelYear", "SPYearVal")
Solar_Panels$SolarPanelYear <- gsub("SolarPanelYear", "", Solar_Panels$SolarPanelYear)

dat <- merge(Customer_Information, Solar_Panels, by="Customer")

rbind(by(dat, list(dat$SubSt_Nm, dat$SolarPanelYear), function(x) {
  mx <- max(sum(x$SPYearVal) * SolarLoad)
}))

##        1   2
## SubA 295 350
## SubB 180 170
## SubC 135 190
## SubD 145 190
```

If you *really* can't install even `reshape2`, then this works with just the base `stats` package:

```
colnames(HouseHoldLoad) <- c("Load.1", "Load.2")
HouseHoldLoad <- reshape(HouseHoldLoad, varying=c("Load.1", "Load.2"), direction="long", timevar="HouseHoldType")[1:2]

colnames(Solar_Panels) <- c("Customer", "SolarPanelYear.1", "SolarPanelYear.2")
Solar_Panels <- reshape(Solar_Panels, varying=c("SolarPanelYear.1", "SolarPanelYear.2"), direction="long", timevar="SolarPanelYear")[1:2]
colnames(Solar_Panels) <- c("Customer", "SPYearVal")
Solar_Panels$SolarPanelYear <- gsub("^[0-9]+\\.", "", rownames(Solar_Panels))

dat <- merge(Customer_Information, Solar_Panels, by="Customer")

rbind(by(dat, list(dat$SubSt_Nm, dat$SolarPanelYear), function(x) {
  mx <- max(sum(x$SPYearVal) * SolarLoad)
}))

##        1   2
## SubA 295 350
## SubB 180 170
## SubC 135 190
## SubD 145 190
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but somehow my work computer seems to have trouble installing the `dplyr` package. Also, this script will be run on a remote server where I sadly cannot install packages, is there any way to do this without dplyr?

Comment: I've had to deal with similar situations (not fun being stuck with limited options). There are two similar solutions in the answer now. I didn't do any timings, but I have to believe they are in order of fastest to slowest, esp on a large data set. Also, if you can manage to use `dplyr` you could even tap into a database vs requiring an extract (which I'm assuming you're working with).

Comment: Allright thanks so much! I'll give it a try and accept when it works!

Comment: One more question, because I am runnning into problems with my actual data set. This is because my actual customer information data is 188k rows long and my actual household load vector is 53k rows. As a result I get the error that `number of rows in the result exceeds maximum vector length`. Is there any way to do this in a quick and efficient manner that does not involve too many for loops?